# when he did, it was usually to make some cynical remark

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I'm reading *Animal Farm* and come across this sentence:

> He seldom talked, and when he did, *it was usually to make some cynical
> remark...*

How can I understand this part *it was usually to make some cynical remark...*?

1. Why was the word *it* used here? What's the grammar used here?
2. What does this *be to* structure mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

> He seldom talked, and when he did [talk], it was usually to make some cynical remark...

The antecedent of the pronoun *it* is the understood word *talk*, (repeated above).

That is, when he did talk, his talking had the purpose of making a cynical remark.

Another example:
When I go out for a walk, *it is to exercise*.
In that example, the antecedent of *it* is *I go for a walk*.

Comment: So if *it* is the understood *talk*, that means *talk* is the subject to this sentence, then it doesn't make sense to me. The remark should be made by *him*, not the *talk*, shouldn't it?

Comment: His talk *was to*, that is, it had the purpose of, making a cynical remark. The talking is done by him, and the purpose of his talk is to make a cynical remark. The subject of the last clause is *it*, which can't have *he* as an antecedent.